# Jwt authentication error in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

I use `tymon/jwt-auth` package for authentication in laravel 5.2 framework
But when i run my login api i got error :

```
  ErrorException in /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php line 317:
  Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

Login code :

```
try
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
    catch (HttpResponseException $e)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => [
                'message'     => 'Invalid auth',
                'status_code' => IlluminateResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
            ]],
            IlluminateResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
            $headers = []
        );
    }
    try
    {
        if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password'), 'status' => 'activate']))
        {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    }
    catch (JWTException $e)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

      $user = User::where('email',$request->get('email'))->where('status','=','activate')->get(['_id','user_type']);
      $this->operator->sign_in($user[0]['_id']);

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            'Authorization'=> 'Bearer' . $token
        ];
        $this->activities->post('login');

       return  response()->json(['_id'=> $user[0]['_id']], 200, $headers);
```

And in auth.php in config folder i have :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'web'),
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => app('config')->get('jwt.user'),
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Notice : when i change `AUTH_GUARD` to `api` in defaults section i got error : 
`call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard' does not have a method 'once'`

Comment: Please help me friends

Comment: Who can help me? :(

Comment: I have some points but they are irrelevant, for your certain problem I have no idea.

Comment: Have you reached anything here?